# Spring Boot started from Runtime.getRuntime().exec() keep waiting until the caller process gets terminated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I Have two spring boot applications, one is called ProcessCenter, that is an API for some mobile and desktop applications, and the other one is called Watcher, responsible for keep everything running.

My problem:

When the Watcher see that ProcessCenter is closed, he calls `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java -jar ProcessCenter.jar" )`, then the ProcessCenter begin to start, but freezes, i got no error, no log, nothing, just keep freeze, until the Watcher is closed, then it resume starting and works just fine

Help anyone?

Comment: Have you tried using ProcessBuilder instead? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: @anders yes, same result, for a quick(but not beautifull) solution we have created a simple jar that just execute the command that comes from the args[] and finish, we know that it's probably not the best way to solve, but it's working

Answer (score 2):

Based on the JDK's Javadoc documentation: "some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock."

You can follow this article that can help you out how to implement an external process call corrrectly, helping you to manage the buffer -> https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2

To summarize, you can create a class that can manage the buffer limitations, processing the output of your program no matter how big it is. An example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
    InputStream is;
    String type;
    OutputStream os;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
    {
        this(is, type, null);
    }
    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type, OutputStream redirect)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.os = redirect;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            if (os != null)
                pw = new PrintWriter(os);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (pw != null)
                    pw.println(line);
                System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
            }
            if (pw != null)
                pw.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioe)
            {
            ioe.printStackTrace();  
            }
    }
}
public class GoodWinRedirect
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if (args.length < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("USAGE java GoodWinRedirect <outputfile>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try
        {            
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("java jecho 'Hello World'");
            // any error message?
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
                StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");            

            // any output?
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
                StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            // any error???
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();        
        } catch (Throwable t)
          {
            t.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, when i start my spring boot jar from Runtime.exec then it waits for the application to close which calls Jar.